# Cant access pod of another Node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, rke

I install a 3 node Kubernetes Cluster with RKE tool. The installation was successful with no errors but I'm unable to ping from one pod to another pod.

If I ping a pod running on worker2 node(NODE-IP-10.222.22.47) I get a response, but no responses from pods running on worker1(NODE-IP-10.222.22.46).
[image]

My Pods are as follows -
[image]

Also I noticed for some pods it has given node-ip addresses. The node IP addresses are
Master1=10.222.22.45

Worker1=10.222.22.46

Worker2=10.222.22.47
cluster_cidr: 10.42.0.0/16

service_cluster_ip_range: 10.43.0.0/16

cluster_dns_server: 10.43.0.10

Overlay network - canal

OS- CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003

Kubernetes - v1.20.8  installed with rke tool

Docker - 20.10.7

Sysctl entries in all nodes

firewall was disabled in all nodes before install.

Check - sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables

net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1

Check - sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables

net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1

Comment: did you set up services? ingress? or simply pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the UDP ports were blocked

Comment: I have the same problem. Which UDP ports were blocked?

Answer (score 0):

- From description and screenshots provided, some addons and
  controllers of master01 do not seem ready, which might need to be
  reconfigured.
- You can also use routes to connect to pods on worker1. Check [this](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/11-pod-network-routes.md#routes) for
  detailed instructions.